# Using non-spatial table in SQL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sql

I am running an MSSQL instance. The SQL Server gets populated with data from another database. Some of the tables contain XY coordinates in regular integer data type and not the geometry/geography format. I am still fiddling around but I am confident I can get the set of X and Y coordinates converted and merged into a geometric column. This then will allow me to plot the points. However, the database also has non-spatial data for drill hole survey orientation. The table contains the HoleID, Depth, Azimuth and Inclination as data. I would like to use the Geoscience plugin to plot the drill hole traces using the desurvey feature in the plugin.

However first I cannot load tables without a spatial column in QGIS. Second if I fake an empty geometry column into the table I can load the table, but the GeoScience plugin does show tables with geospatial data for the survey details.

Is there a way for QGIS to load non-spatial data from a SQL Server?

Additional details:

I ticked the box in the server settings to show tables without geometry data. The table shows up in the SQL environment, but I cannot view the table or use it. The following error message will come up using non-spatial tables:

> Error retrieving fields information for uri: dbname='DataBaseName' host=IP\SQLInstance user='User' disableInvalidGeomtryHandling='1' table="dbo"."Drilling"

There is no difference if I tick the "Skip invalid geometry handling" option in the Server settings.

Looking at the debugger I found the following error:

> Error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'geometry_columns'. QODBC3: Unable to execute statement

The table can get added as a layer, but I will come with a warning sign saying:

> Unavailable Layer! Layer data source could not be found. Click to set a new data source.

When I want to look at the Attribute Data, the option is greyed out. I am a bit perplex that QGIS can open a CSV as a table just fine, but SQL data appears to require the geometry data type, otherwise QGIS just freaks out.

Comment: did you check the `also list tables with no geometry` checkbox (at least that's how postgis does it)

Comment: There is a similar ticket https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46994.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. I suggest you first put more effort into adding and populating the geometry column. The hardest part of GIS  is getting good performance from non-standard data. Once you have a geometry you can index it, and most of that pain goes away.

Comment: @ user30184, it appears to be the same issue but i cannot find a solution on github.
@ Vince: I got one table containing the coordinates of the drill holes and I can get the geometry column added. Not succeeded yet, but getting there. However, the second table is the one without any geospatial data. It only contains holeID and the orientation the hole is going. a geometry column for that table does not make sense in my eyes.